# findFragmentById returns null value

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-support-library, androidx, fragmentmanager

I created 2 fragments a detailFrag and listFrag but when I'm trying to hide/show a particular fragment using fragment manager the `findFragmentById(R.id.detailFrag)` and `findFragmentById(R.id.listFrag)` returns a null value.
I searched for similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me .

Here I'm pasting the code of my MainActivity file where the error is being generated:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvDescription=findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

    if(findViewById(R.id.layout_portrait) !=null)
    {
        FragmentManager manager=this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .hide(manager.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFrag))
                .show(manager.findFragmentById(R.id.listFrag))
                .commit();
    }

    if(findViewById(R.id.layout_land)!=null)
    {
        FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .show(manager.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFrag))
                .show(manager.findFragmentById(R.id.listFrag))
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Here the FragmentManager class I have used is of *Androidx.fragment.app* because I'm unable to import the *android.app.support.v4.Fragment* 
I have tried `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` in build.gradle file but it shows an error.
I was supposed to use the support library v4 here but due to that problem I'm unable to use it,not sure if that might have caused the problem.

XML Files:

MainActivity(portrait)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_portrait"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentspractice.ListFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFrag"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentspractice.DetailFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity(Landscape):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_land"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentspractice.ListFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFrag"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentspractice.DetailFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
```

listFrag:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ListFrag">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

detailFrag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detailFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailFrag">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are these ID's defined? Also, when are you adding these fragments? Please provide your layout xmls

Comment: The ListFrag , DetailFrag and MainActivity all are present within the app>java>com.example.fragmentspractice